# Foundation Switch not enabling

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4's Switch.  I'm disabling it on the php page unless and until the user is logged in, at which point, I'm programmatically enabling it, changing the font color, and checking the default value.  If the user is logged in from the initial load of the PHP page, $there_are_prefs will be 1.  The font color and removal of the DIV's title is working properly, but the enabling is not and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

The HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 small-centered columns">
    <div class="switch medium round" id="pref_switch" <? if(!$there_are_prefs){ ?>title="Please Login"<? } ?>>
      <input id="x" name="switch-x" type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('use_prefs').value='yes';" <? if($there_are_prefs){ ?>checked<? }else{?>disabled<? } ?>>
      <label for="x" id="lblUse" onclick="" style="color:<? if($there_are_prefs){ ?>black<? }else{ ?>grey<? } ?>;">Use Store Prefs</label>

      <input id="x1" name="switch-x" type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('use_prefs').value='no';" <? if(!$there_are_prefs){ ?>checked disabled<? } ?>>
      <label for="x1" id="lblDont" onclick="" style="color:<? if($there_are_prefs){ ?>black<? }else{ ?>grey<? } ?>;">Don't Use</label>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#x").prop('disabled',false).prop("checked", true);
$("#x1").prop('disabled',false);
// change the font color back to black lblUse, lblDont
$('#lblUse').css('color', 'black');
$('#lblDont').css('color', 'black');
// remove the title from #pref_switch
$('#pref_switch').prop('title', '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I'm such an idiot.  The page has lots of included files, including the Login/Logout logic and I had 2 sets of Switches on the page with the same id since I copied and pasted the example of Foundation's site.